# Access and evaluate deep nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, nested, ecmascript-next

Let's say I have the following nested object expression where I am using **Oliver Steele's nested object access pattern** and I wonder if anyone knows a clear and better way of accessing deep nested object properties.

```
const value = (((object.prop1 || {}).prop2 || {}).prop3) && (((object.prop1 || {}).prop2|| {}).prop4);
```

I have found that there's an alternative way which makes the expression to become clear and more understandable by using optional chaining. However, optional chaining it's not compatible with IE:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
const value = object.prop1?.prop2?.prop3 && object.prop1?.prop2?.prop4;
```

So for this reason, I was wondering if anyone knows a clear way for deep nested objects than Oliver's pattern and that is also compatible with all browsers.

Thank you so much in advance.

By the way, by using the latest version of **Bable** on a project, will that allow us to use that the javascript **optional chaining** on the browser where it is not natively implemented such as Internet Explorer?

Comment: Look at this article on [4 ways](https://medium.com/better-programming/4-ways-to-safely-access-nested-objects-in-vanilla-javascript-8671d09348a8).

Comment: Just wanted to say THANKS because this question made me research and learn about Optional chaining which is freaking great. Turns out it was just implemented in Chrome 80 (current release) and still not availavle in latest public release of Firefox. Feel like a pioneer.